# Differential equation in Complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this differential equation
$$Z'=Z^*$$
such that $Z$ is complex numbers and $Z^*$ is the conjugate of $Z$?

Sketch the phase portraits of solutions.

Comment: If it can help : Z''=Z

Comment: Also possibly helpful: you can interpret it as a system of linear equations of the form $\begin{pmatrix}u'\\v'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$, where $u,v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z$, respectively.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, you're missing something.  It is not holomorphic, because the right side is not a holomorphic function of $Z$.

Comment: So $Z$ is a function of a *real* (rather than *complex*) argument? **That** is what I was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing

$z = x + iy, \tag 1$

where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are functions of the independent variable $t$, we have

$\dot z = \dot x + i \dot y, \tag 2$

and

$z^\ast = x - iy; \tag 3$

then the given equation

$\dot z = z^\ast \tag 4$

becomes

$\dot x + i \dot y = x - iy; \tag 5$

equating the real and imaginary parts we find

$\dot x = x \tag 6$

and

$\dot y = -y; \tag 7$

to proceed further, we assign $z$ the initial condition

$z(t_0) = x(t_0) + iy(t_0), \tag 8$

which in fact initializes $x$ and $y$; now (6) and (7) have the well-known unique solutions

$x(t)= x(t_0)e^{t - t_0}, \tag{9}$

$y(t) = y(t_0)e^{t_0 - t}, \tag{10}$

whence

$z(t)  = x(t_0)e^{t - t_0} + iy(t_0)e^{t_0 - t}. \tag{11}$

In order to sketch the phase portrait of the system (4), we first take note of the fact that (9) and (10) together yield

$x(t)y(t) = x(t_0)y(t_0), \tag{12}$

which whenever

$x(t_0) \ne 0 \ne y(t_0) \tag{13}$

shows that the solution curves lie in he hyperbolas

$xy = x(t_0)y(t_0) \tag{14}$

in the $xy$-plane $\Bbb R^2$; if precisely *one* of $x(t_0)$, $y(t_0)$ does not vanish, then the corresponding phase curve is either the positive or negative $x$ or $y$ half-axis.  For example, if

$x(t_0) > 0, \; y(t_0) = 0, \tag{15}$

the solution curve traverses the entire positive $x$-axis as $-\infty \to t \to \infty$.  Similar results apply when

$x(t_0) = 0, \; y(t_0) \ne 0 \tag{16}$

etc; the reader may easily complete the necessary details; finally when

$x(t_0) = 0 = y(t_0) \tag{17}$

the phase curve is the single point $(0, 0)$.  With these facts in mind, the phase portrait of (4) may be sketched with little additional effort.