# non-linear Differential equation in Complex numbers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

[Differential equation in Complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922797/differential-equation-in-complex-numbers)

Basically the same question, but different equation: $ \frac{1}{z} \dot{z}^2 >0 $.

So far I just set the equation $=1$ to get any solution (there's no specific initial condition).

$\frac{1}{z}\dot{z}^2=1 \Rightarrow$ $z(t)=\dot{z}^2$ and using $z(t)=u(t)+i\cdot v(t)$ we get $\dot{u}^2-\dot{v}^2+2i\dot{u}\dot{v}=u+iv$

Now as mentioned in the above accepted answer we try to get a solution by setting equal real and imaginary parts of both sides, i.e. $\dot{u}^2=u$ and $-\dot{v}^2+2iuv=v$ or is the last equation wrong?

For the real part I get by separating $u(t)=\frac{t^2}{4}$ but I think I made a mistake for the imaginary part.

Can you help me out? Thanks ahead :)

PS: the solution is supposed to look like a hyperbola opening up to the right, but I don't see that yet either

Comment: Are you solving $\dot{z}^{2}/z > 0$ or $ \dot{z}^{2}/z = 1$?

Comment: the second one, but I'd also like to know anything about the first one's solution